# Smtp Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail, codeigniter-3

In order to train me on codeigniter I decided to set up an application protected by login password.
In case of password lost I have a function of confirmation by mail. but there...

> 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP j39-v6sm10096073wre.44 - gsmtp
>
> hello: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [86.236.5.51]
>
> 250-SIZE 35882577
>
> 250-8BITMIME
>
> 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
>
> 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>
> 250-PIPELINING
>
> 250-CHUNKING
>
> 250 SMTPUTF8
>
> from: 250 2.1.0 OK j39-v6sm10096073wre.44 - gsmtp
>
> to: 250 2.1.5 OK j39-v6sm10096073wre.44 - gsmtp
>
> data: 354  Go ahead j39-v6sm10096073wre.44 - gsmtp
>
> quit:
>
> L'erreur SMTP suivante s'est produite :
>
> L'erreur SMTP suivante s'est produite :
>
> Impossible d'envoyer des emails avec la méthode SMTP de PHP. Votre serveur ne 
>   doit pas être configuré pour pouvoir utiliser cette méthode.
>
> Date: Sun, 19 Aug 2018 08:51:39 +0000
>
> From:
>
> Return-Path:
>
> To: tony.amprou@gmail.com
>
> Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?\r=20test?=
>
> Reply-To:
>
> User-Agent: CodeIgniter
>
> X-Sender: tony.amprou@gmail.com
>
> X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
>
> X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
>
> Message-ID: <5b792f9b817d1@gmail.com>
>
> Mime-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>
> Bonjour

I do not understand the mistake I could make. Here is my code.

```html
public function oubli() 
 {
 $this->load->helper("form");
 $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('mail','mail','trim|required');
  if($this->form_validation->run() ==false) 
  {
   $this->load->view('login/oubli');
  }
  else
  { 
  $mail = $this->input->post('mail');
  $this->auth_user->oubli_pass($mail);
  $nombre = $this->auth_user->nombre;
   if($nombre == '1') 
   {
         $this->load->library('email');
         $this->config->load('email', TRUE);
         $this->email->initialize($this->config->item('email'));
         $this->email->from('tony.amprou@gmail.com');
         $this->email->to($this->input->post('mail'));
         $this->email->subject('test');
         $this->email->message('Bonjour');
          if($this->email->send())
          {
          $data['result_class'] = "alert-success";
          $data['result_message'] ="Un email de reinitialisation vient de vous etre envoyé";
    }
    else
    {
    $data['result_class'] = "alert-danger";
             $data['result_message'] = "Votre message n'a pas pu être envoyé. Nous mettons tout en oeuvre pour résoudre le problème.";
             $data['result_message'] .= "<pre>\n";
             $data['result_message'] .= $this->email->print_debugger();
             $data['result_message'] .= "</pre>\n";
             $this->email->clear(); 
    }
   $this->load->view('login/oubli_result', $data);
   }
   else
   {
    $data['mail_error'] = "L'adresse mail est inconnu";
    $this->load->view('login/oubli', $data); 
   }

  }
 }
```

And my config files ...

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['protocol']  = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.gmail.com";
$config['smtp_user'] = "tony.amprou@gmail.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "MON MOT DE PASSE";
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['charset']   = 'utf-8';
$config['newline']   = '\r\n';
$config['crlf']   = '\n';
$config['mailtype']  = 'text';
$config['starttls']  =  'true';
$config['smtp_crypto'] = "ssl";
$config['ssl'] = "ssl";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I added in my controller the line "$ this-> email-> set_newline (" \ r \ n ");".

The email is sent well. That said I do not understand why this little command line solve my problem ...

```
$ this-> email-> set_newline (" \ r \ n ");".
```

Comment: Not working for me , getting same error : 220 `smtp.gmail.com ESMTP j39-v6sm10096073wre.44 - gsmtp`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in your gmail you have enabled "Allow less secure app" settings. and check your recent login activity in gmail there you may need to allow access for your server.
After this things test it again if it still doesn't work got to this URL https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha click "continue" and test it again. Now it should work

Comment: thank you for your answer. I activate the gmail security options but the error persists. However in the gmail connection details the smtp connection does not appear.

For isolated problem I also change the timezone of php but without result. I also backup my controller in utf8 but without result.

But I ask myself the question. Will Gmail refuse to send an email to the same person logged in? I do tests and I come back to you.

Comment: My pleasure! But timezone is not related to this issue. When you use gmail smtp settings to send email. Gmail will block access first time, you need to go to recent activity section of your gmail account and mark the activity as yours (Gmail will ask something like this) "This was you" ? 
As like we get an email when we login to gmail with different machine.